What is the best bound on degree of every vertex in a graph in order it has no independent subset of cardinality $k$?
We are given a graph $G$ that has $n$ vertices. Every vertex in $G$ has the same degree $d$. What is the best lower bound on $d$ in order $G$ has no independent subset on $k$ vertices? Obviously we can give the following trivial estimation: $d \geq n-k+1$. Can we make it less than $n-k+1$? I don't know any graph which has independent subset on $k$ vertices and at the same time $d$ would be equal to $n-k$.

What do you mean by “in order $G$ has no independent subset on $k$ vertices”? Perhaps to ensure that $G$ has…?

In other words, do you mean “What is the least $d$ so that no $d$-regular graph has an induced $\overline{K_k}$”?

@PaulTanenbaum yes, exactly

A $d$-regular graph is always $d+1$ colorable, so we always have an independent set of size $\frac{n}{d+1}$. This bound is achieved a disjoint collection of $K_{d+1}$.
Outside of these examples and of odd cycles, a $d$-regular graph is always $d$ colorable (Brook's theorem), so it has an independent set of size $\frac{n}{d}$. We can easily construct graphs with an independent set of size $\frac{n}{d}$ by taking a disjoint union of $K_d$ graphs and adding edges to make the graph regular.
